# How can I add numbers across columns in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, calculated-columns

In my .csv file, I have four columns of numbers defined as follows:
`aIN = $item1.IN`
`aOUT = $item1.OUT`
`bIN = $item2.IN`
`bOUT = $item2.OUT`

The numbers themselves are a mix of integers and decimals. I am trying to find a total-IN column and a total-OUT column using the follows:
`total-IN = aIN + bIN`
`total-OUT = aOUT + bOUT`

Let's say I have...
`aIN    aOUT    bIN    bOUT`
`0.1    0.2     0.3    0.4`
`1      2       3      4`
`0.5    0.6     0.7    0.8`
`5      6       7      8`

What I would like is...
`aIN    aOUT    bIN    bOUT    total-IN    total-OUT`
`0.1    0.2     0.3    0.4     0.4         0.6`
`1      2       3      4       4           6`
`0.5    0.6     0.7    0.8     1.2         1.4`
`5      6       7      8       12          14`

My method is not working. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: "My method is not working" - what method?

Comment: `total-IN = aIN + bIN` and `total-OUT = aOUT + bOUT`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using

- a `Select-Object` to append total columns
- iterate through source with a ForEach
- and cast as a double

---

```
$CsvData = Import-Csv '.\testfile.csv' | Select-Object *,'total-IN','total-OUT'

ForEach ($Row in $CsvData) {
   $Row.'total-IN'  = [double]$Row.aIN  + $Row.bIN
   $Row.'total-OUT' = [double]$Row.aOUT + $Row.bOUT
}

$CsvData | Format-Table -AutoSize
$CsvData | Export-Csv .\your.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

You could also do with a `calculated property`

```
$CsvData = @"
aIN,aOUT,bIN,bOUT
0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4
1,2,3,4
0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8
5,6,7,8
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv | Select-Object *,
    @{n='total-IN';e={[double]$_.aIN  + $_.bIN}},
    @{n='total-OUT';e={[double]$_.aOUT  + $_.bOUT}}

$CsvData | Format-Table -AutoSize
$CsvData | Export-Csv .\your.csv -NoTypeInformation
```